# Trouble with Using IFS with AND in Excel - Receiving error message that it is not a formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am attempting to use an IFS statement that when 2 separate cells equal the criteria, I want it to return the data from another cell.  What I've tried so far is:

```
=IFS(AND(B7="A", A9="Buck Openings"), X178, $0.00), (B7="Albert", A9="Buck Openings"), X56, $0.00), (B7="Arabella III", A9="Buck Openings"), X59, $0.00, (B7="Ashmere", A9="Buck Openings"), Y65, $0.00)
```

I receive an error that it is not a formula.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong - or if there is a better way to do this please?

Thanks very much for your assistance.

I am unable to find why I am receiving an error message that it is not a formula.

Comment: The first problem is `$0.00`. Just use `0`. Though what are you trying to do exactly? Sample data and the expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFS uses pairs, "if true then this"  You are trying to add a FALSE to each test.
Instead we need to just list the test and what to do if true:

```
=IFS(
    AND(B7="A", A9="Buck Openings"), X178, 
    AND(B7="Albert", A9="Buck Openings"), X56, 
    AND(B7="Arabella III", A9="Buck Openings"), X59, 
    AND(B7="Ashmere", A9="Buck Openings"), Y65, 
    TRUE, 0)
```

Now it easy to see the pairs.

Comment: Thank you Scott - I no longer get a formula error, however, it does not return the value at the end of each line (X178, X56, etc.)  Any other ideas?

Comment: so it only returns `0`?

Comment: Thank you - I checked all the cell addresses and was able to figure out the issue.  I sure appreciate your lesson on IFS AND - that really helped me!  :)

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: The checkmark has been clicked.  I hope this may help someone else in the future too!  :)